# Getting incompitable type error though I had used Interger.parseInt

Tags: java, compiler-errors

```
    My program is to sort numbers in ascending order and finally merge the answer which should also be in ascending order.
    Compilation Errors -
    **My Error****
    Main.java:71: error: incompatible types
    k=Integer.parseInt(res);
    ^
    required: int[]
    found: int
    1 error
```

I had tried a lot to remove this error but could not find any logic.

```
    **this my code**
import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    public class Main
    {

        public static void main(String[]args)
        {
            int w=0,x=0;
            int[] k=new int[100];
            Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
         int   n=sc.nextInt();
            if(n<0)
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid Input");
                System.exit(1);
                        }
              int[] m=new int[n];
              for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
              {
                  m[i]=sc.nextInt();
              }
              for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
              {
                for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++) 
                {
                    if(m[i]>m[j])
                    {
                        int temp=m[i];
                        m[i]=m[j];
                        m[j]=temp;
                    }
                }
              }
              for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
              {
                  System.out.print(m[i]+" ");
              }
              w=m[n-1];
              System.out.print(w);

    int v=sc.nextInt();
    if(v<0)
    {
        System.out.print("Invalid Input");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    int[]r=new int[v];
    for(int i=0;i<v;i++)
    {
        r[i]=sc.nextInt();
        }
        for(int i=0;i<v;i++)
        {
            for(int j=i+1;j<v;j++)
            {
                if(r[i]>r[j])
                {
                    int temp=r[i];
                    r[i]=r[j];
                    r[j]=temp;
                }
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<v-1;i++)
        {
            System.out.print(r[i]+" ");
        }
        x=r[v-1];
        System.out.print(x);
            String res=" "+w+x;
             k=Integer.parseInt(res);// error in this line;
        Arrays.sort(k);
        System.out.println(k);

    }
    }`
```

The final K is used merge the output of w and x which should also be in ascending order.
Is there any other method to resolve this. 
Thank you in advance

Comment: You're trying to assign an `int` value to `k`, but the type of `k` is an `int[]`. You probably meant something like `k[i] = Integer.parseInt(res);` but we can't easily tell for sure as we've no idea what your code is meant to be doing.

Comment: Additionally, please note that it's worth cutting problems down to a [mcve] before posting, and formatting it carefully. Currently you've posted about 75 lines of code, very little of which is relevant to your immediate problem, and the indentation is all over the place. We love to help people on Stack Overflow, but it's intended to be a repository of high quality questions and answers - think about how much of your code is going to be relevant to anyone else reading your question in years to come.

Comment: Hint: the error message tells you **all** you need to know. It tells you which line, which variable, what is expected, and what is given. Just *read* those messages carefully! This is super-basic stuff, and you should not get into the mode of turning such things into questions on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

`k` is an `int[]` (array of `int`) not an `int`.

Therefore

```
k = Integer.parseInt(res);
```

should be

```
k[someIndex] = Integer.parseInt(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the returned value to an actual value (cell) from your array like:

```
for(int i=0; i<v; i++) {
      ....
    k[i] = Integer.parseInt(res);
      ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Eran . 
incompatible types generally means left part of = and right part of = are NOT the same type. It is not a difficult error .
In your case the right part is an int while left part is int array , so just adding index to left part is fine.